# ODOO 10 Uncaught TypeError: split is not a function

Tags: javascript, odoo-10

I'am facing this problem when I'am trying to get/search name of partner using Many2one fields in my custom models.
I'am trying to compare with the declaration of partner_id in sale/Quotation module, but I didn't find any difference, Btw When I'am trying search name of customer in quotation this error doesn't display.

Declaration field :*.py

```
partner_id = fields.Many2one('res.partner', string="Client", required=True)
```

Declaration field :*.xml

```
<group name="partner_info" string="Info client">
    <field name="partner_id" />

    <label for="street" string="Address"/>
    <div class="o_address_format">
        <field name="street" placeholder="Street..." class="o_address_street" />
        <field name="city" placeholder="City" class="o_address_city" />
        <field name="state_id" class="o_address_state" placeholder="State" options="{&quot;no_open&quot;: True}"/>
        <field name="zip" placeholder="ZIP" class="o_address_zip" />
    </div>
    <label for="street" string="Contact"/>
    <div name="contact">
        <field name="phone" widget="phone" placeholder="Tél ° "/>
        <field name="email" widget="email" placeholder="E-mail"/>
    </div>

</group>
```

Thanks in advance
[image]

Comment: `x[1]` is not a string? Without more information, like a [mcve], it's going to be hard to help

Comment: What is the typeof `x[1]` here?

Comment: @khelilimiliana updated with what? we need to see console.log(x)

Comment: @palsh, I'am using odoo10, x is relation field, in fact x is integer, but when we use the field it will be work as a string, so split is permitted

Comment: @mplungjan, The console doesn't display any error, this from the interface

Comment: @DaniyalLukmanov, Is not hard, but it doesn't display any error in log , I'am using pycharm, and this error come from ODOO 10 basic function

Comment: Then the problem comes from Odoo

Comment: I am not talking about console errors. We need proof that x[1] is a string which it likely is not

Comment: @mplungjan, I know that split works just with string and not with integer, in fact x is integer column in my DB table (is the id of table), in the same table there is another column name, using a odoo function, I'can search with the name and not the ID of table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After deep searching, I could find the source of problem, when we put a letter in the partner fields, It will automatically call the function name_search in base module, witch search in res_partner table using SQL query :

```
select id 
from res_partner 
where 'entered value' [ '=' or 'like' or 'ilike' or '=like' or 
                        '=ilike'] [email, or name, ref ]...`;
```

This query return a list of tuples

`[(id1, 'partner name1'), (id2, 'partner name2')]`

and the function return the second elm from every tuple witch is the name of partner, but if you have some partner with name field is empty the error will displayed, and this explains why some letters don't generate the error message. Some letters don't generate the error message because the SQL query search based on multiple fields as Email, reference, name of partner.

And the existence of this function just in partner, and not in every table explains that the main objective of the function is to allow us to search based on other fields [email, reference ...]

The path of function : `/addons/base/res/res_partner.py` line 640

```
@api.model
def name_search(self, name, args=None, operator='ilike', limit=100):
    if args is None:
        args = []
    if name and operator in ('=', 'ilike', '=ilike', 'like', '=like'):
        self.check_access_rights('read')
        where_query = self._where_calc(args)
        self._apply_ir_rules(where_query, 'read')
        from_clause, where_clause, where_clause_params = where_query.get_sql()
        where_str = where_clause and (" WHERE %s AND " % where_clause) or ' WHERE '

        # search on the name of the contacts and of its company
        search_name = name
        if operator in ('ilike', 'like'):
            search_name = '%%%s%%' % name
        if operator in ('=ilike', '=like'):
            operator = operator[1:]

        unaccent = get_unaccent_wrapper(self.env.cr)

        query = """SELECT id
                     FROM res_partner
                  {where} ({email} {operator} {percent}
                       OR {display_name} {operator} {percent}
                       OR {reference} {operator} {percent})
                       -- don't panic, trust postgres bitmap
                 ORDER BY {display_name} {operator} {percent} desc,
                          {display_name}
                """.format(where=where_str,
                           operator=operator,
                           email=unaccent('email'),
                           display_name=unaccent('display_name'),
                           reference=unaccent('ref'),
                           percent=unaccent('%s'))

        where_clause_params += [search_name]*4
        if limit:
            query += ' limit %s'
            where_clause_params.append(limit)
        self.env.cr.execute(query, where_clause_params)
        partner_ids = map(lambda x: x[0], self.env.cr.fetchall())

        if partner_ids:
            return self.browse(partner_ids).name_get()
        else:
            return []
    return super(Partner, self).name_search(name, args, operator=operator, limit=limit)
```

the error line :

```
if partner_ids:
    return self.browse(partner_ids).name_get()
else:
    return []
```

Comment: So it returns an array sometimes and a string sometimes? Not fun...

Comment: @evolutionxbox it returns an array of tuple `[(integer, string), ....]`, but if string is None it will returns `Boolean` with value `False` instead